# How can I rename sheets when combining Workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to combine workbooks from a folder, and I found the below code which should do exactly what I need. The code is from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/956804-merge-all-workbooks-worksheets-folder-vba-prompt-select-folder.html).

The issue I am encountering, that the worksheets in my workbooks all have the same long title, and it seems to crash the Sub as excel can't auto rename the sheets due to conflict (e.g. there is no room to append with (2) and (3) etc.).

How can I add onto the code to rename the sheets something arbitrary, e.g. Copied1, Copied 2, etc... ?

```
Sub MergeWorkbooks()

Dim FolderName As String
Dim directory As String, fileName As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    On Error Resume Next
    FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

directory = FolderName & "\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xls?")

Do While fileName <> ""
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
    ws.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Next ws
wb2.Close savechanges:=False
fileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just rename them before you copy them? so before `ws.copy` do a `ws.Name = <new Name>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable `i` to rename your sheets before moving them to your other book. The `i` corresponds to the book the sheet came from in your loop.

So the 5th book will have a sheet name of `Sheet1 5` and the 6th book will be `Sheet1 6` and so on for every sheet in every book.

---

```
Dim i As Long
i = 1

Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(directory & Filename)
        For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
            ws.Name = ws.Name & Chr(32) & i               '<-- Rename
            ws.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Next ws
    wb2.Close savechanges:=False
    Filename = Dir
    i = i + 1                                             '<-- Increment i for next bok
Loop
```

*This will only work if the code is ran once - If you try to re-run the code on the same books with similar names, the index `i` will have already been used. If this is a problem, you can rename the sheets to corrospond with the number of sheets that are on the book (`wb1.Sheets.Count`)*

Comment: Thanks! I had it in my mind that I needed to do a nested loop, but I see now I can just increment in the Do While Filename <> " " loop. Much more straightforward than I thought it would be.

Comment: Finally had a chance to try, and yes, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of **urdearboy**'s response, I added user prompts to choose whether a batch rename is wanted, and if it is, to choose the batch name. It's nice to have the option when needed!

```
Sub MergeWorkbooks()

Dim FolderName As String
Dim directory As String, fileName As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim xAppend As String

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    On Error Resume Next
    FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

directory = FolderName & "\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xls?")

'Prompt user to decide if batch rename is required
iAnswer = MsgBox("Would you like to batch rename the worksheets?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")

    'vbYes: Rename Worksheets
    If iAnswer = vbYes Then

1:

        xAppend = InputBox(Prompt:= _
                    "Enter new batch name for worksheets." _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Sheets will be appended with number based on the order in which they are copied." _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "If 'Cancel' is selected, worksheets will be renamed as number only, based on order in which they are copied.", _
                    Title:="Naming Convention")

                        If InStr(xAppend, "<") > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, ">") > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, ":") > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, Chr(34)) > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, "/") > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, "\") > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, "|") > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, "?") > 0 _
                            Or InStr(xAppend, "*") > 0 _
                                 Then
                                    MsgBox "Suggested filename contains an invalid character"
                                    GoTo 1
                        End If

            Dim i As Long
            i = 1

            Do While fileName <> ""
                Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
                    For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
                        ws.Name = xAppend & i                       '<-- Rename
                        ws.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    Next ws
                wb2.Close savechanges:=False
                fileName = Dir
                i = i + 1                                            '<-- Increment i for next bok
            Loop


        'vbNo: Rename Worksheets
        ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then

            Do While fileName <> ""
                Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
                    For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
                        ws.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Next ws
            wb2.Close savechanges:=False
            fileName = Dir
            Loop

        'vb Canel: Exit
        Else
            Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub
```